# Undefined reference to GetStockObject@4

Tags: c, windows, eclipse

I've created a program in Eclipse / MinGW / C (project type: C) which should just present an empty window. It also has the folowing line:

```
wndclassex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
```

The call to `GetStockObject()` produces a compiler error:

> Z:/mtsts_workspace/MTSTS/Debug/../WinMain.c:29:
>   undefined reference to
>   `GetStockObject@4'

Has anyone an idea what's wrong ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144925%28VS.85%29.aspx), and make sure you link to the required libraries (`-lgdi32`).

Comment: I have included windows.h And with Visual Studio the code was OK.

Comment: Including doesn't help; this is a link-type error. You need to specify that the code should be linked with gdi32.lib, where the actual code for GetStockObject() resides.

Comment: How can I "specify the code" that should be linked with gdi32.lib ???
Normaly I just put in the #include's and then simply call the functions ...

Comment: Add the library gdi32.lib to your Eclipse project.

Comment: @MarcusTik Using `#include` does absolutely nothing when the code resides in a non-standard library. You must tell the compiler to link to the required libraries, the `#include` statements are consumed by the preprocessor and never seen by the compiler so they can't help there.

Comment: If you compile with gcc, it will look like `gcc name.c -lgdi32`

Comment: Add that (-lgdi32) in Eclipse's linking options.

Answer (score 4):

Best guess: you need to link `gdi32.lib`.

Answer (score 0):

If your Win32 application is a non trivial GUI you will need these link directives to bring in the right libraries:

```
-lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lcomctl32 -lm -mwindows
```

- `lgdi32`:    graphics subsystem
- `luser32`:   user subsystem
- `lkernel32`: kernel subsystem
- `lcomctl32`: common control dll versions
- `lm`:        math libraries
- `mwindows`:  standalone GUI (console free) application

The above directives tell the linker which libraries to link; this is a different concept than compiler header files which define the library function prototypes (among other things). For instance, declaring `<math.h>` does not automatically link the math lib; you need `-lm`. Also, `<wingdi.h>` does not automatically link the gdi32 lib; you need `-lgdi32`.

At the command line you literally specify `-lgdi32` (along with others) after all your file names. Otherwise, how you specify how to link the various subsystem libraries depends on the IDE you are using for the specific build target you're working on. Check your documentation for the IDE of choice.